# C++ Builder exporting cdecl for cross platform use

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, cross-platform, c++builder

I have a library (dll) originally written in MSVS that I need to make cross platform (Mac/Win). I started using XCode but with the new Embarcadero C++ builder XE3 I am thinking that one development environment would be a better way to go.
The host application is written in Delphi so more reason to move it to one set of tools.

For my existing code everything is cdecl but I cannot get this to work on C++ builder. If I convert it to stdcall then it works fine but as I understand it I need to use cdecl when using the library under OSX.

In MSVC I export my functions like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Init(char * init_dir, DebugCallbackFunc f, DeviceCallbackFunc f1)
```

In C++ Builder I am exporting like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int _cdecl Init(char * init_dir, DebugCallbackFunc f, DeviceCallbackFunc f1)
```

The problem is that the Delphi host application always returns NULL with GetProcAddress when I use cdecl but works fine if I change it to stdcall.

```
TUDMXInit = function(p: PAnsiChar; f: TDebugCallbackFunc; f1: TDeviceCallbackFunc): integer; cdecl;
```

I would also appreciate an example of the best way to handle the '_' that is suppose to prefix the exported function under OSX. Should I just use conditionals to add this at the front of all functions?

Thanks in advance.
Martin

Comment: There is more than just a _ in the C++ library names, do that issue as another question

Comment: Personally I think a .def file is the most effective way to specify your exports. Well, that's for Windows. Not sure about OSX.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way of doing this is to use macros. declspec and cdecl/stdcall are Windows specific.
The call in OSX(and other Unix) you want is

```
extern "C" int Init(char * init_dir, DebugCallbackFunc f, DeviceCallbackFunc f1)
```

So the usual way is to define a macro e.g. DLL_EXPORT see the Boost libraries for examples
e.g. from [Serialisation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/archive/detail/decl.hpp) or a simpler description from [Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8721)

Assuming WINDOWS is defined in your build for Windows libraries

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
  #define DLLEXPORT  __declspec( dllexport )
#else
  #define DLLEXPORT
#endif
```

Also you can make this define behave correctly for when building the DLL as here or calling the DLL when you need `__declspec( dllimport )`

Comment: Does a macro make the name-mangling issue (where GetProcAddress fails) go away by itself? You didn't address that aspect of the question.

Comment: @RobKennedy - as noted in my comment that is a different question - actually even worse as GetProcAddress is a Windows API call and I suspect no direct equivalent in OSX, you need to look at bundles and I am no sure that Delphi is available for OSX so affects totally what the OP is trying to do,

Comment: Yes, I understand about conditional exports using #define but the central part of my question is why cdecl is not working with C++ builder at all. On the delphi side the imports are cdecl and that works with the MSVS version of the library.

Comment: AS noted in my comment the name mangling etc in OSX should be a separate question - as your question has been read as both the answers as more how to set up the code (Basically the C++ ABI of cdecl  is Windows specific and has nothing like that on Unix)

Answer (score 2):

The way I handle such differences is always the same basic idea: look at how each compiler does it, and come up with a macro or a set of macros that can generate all the required forms without being too cumbersome to use.

For your _cdecl, a simple macro like "EXPORT_CDECL" would seem to suffice; you can then set this to expand to nothing, "_cdecl", or "stdcall" as required by the compiler.

You can also use something like this to add something to names, such as `#define EXPORT_NAME(Name) _##Name`

You can, of course, also make a "big" macro that takes the individual components (return type, function name, function parameters) and spits out the entire result-line.